# Page Speed Not Removing Comments

Tags: html, tomcat, nginx, google-pagespeed

I'm trying to use Nginx and Google's pagespeed mod to eliminate white space and html comments but it isn't working.  I'm running Tomcat 8 on the back end.  We can see in the log file that pagespeed is being loaded by Nginx. Below is my conf file.   Any ideas why its not working?

```
server {
    pagespeed on;
    pagespeed EnableFilters remove_comments;
    pagespeed EnableFilters collapse_whitespace;
    pagespeed FileCachePath /run/shm/pagespeed_cache;
        pagespeed RewriteLevel CoreFilters;
    #pagespeed RespectVary on; #Respecting Vary Headers
    #pagespeed DisableRewriteOnNoTransform off; #Honoring no-transform Cache-Control Headers
    #pagespeed LowercaseHtmlNames on; #Lower-casing HTML element and attribute names
    #pagespeed ModifyCachingHeaders off; #Preserving HTML caching headers
    #pagespeed XHeaderValue "Powered By ngx_pagespeed"; #Specifying the value for the PageSpeed header
    #pagespeed StaticAssetPrefix /custom/static/; #Configuring the location of static assets
    #pagespeed PreserveUrlRelativity on; #Preserve URL Relativity
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name mysite.org www.mysite.org;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The server block you show in your question does not handle any actual HTML content, as it just redirects to https via the `return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;`-directive. Enable the pagespeed module in the https server block, too.

Comment: Nice catch.  I'll give it try.